# How to copy text from within the text editor nano in the context of a Termux session (on Android) to the Android system clipboard

Tags: android, copy, clipboard, termux, nano

I am editing text in nano. I can't copy text, neither within nano itself nor to the Android system clipboard (where I need the copied text to go).

I tried:

1. selecting text using Strg.-M-6 (works), then Alt-6 or Alt-Shift-6 to copy it (selectin marker disappears, text is not copied).
2. double-clicking on any part of the text with the mouse. This, contrary to expectation, does not select anything. I cannot select any text using the mouse in nano under Termux.
3. I cut and pasted the text passage. This was successful in so far as to put the selected text into the nano-internal clipboard. But I cannot use the cut text in other applications, it just comes out empty.
4. I long-tapped on some part of the text, then the Termux-contextual menu appears, including the option to "copy". Selecting this option, no text was copied to the Android system clipboard (where I need it).

I am at a loss. Please advise on how to achieve this.

I tried: detailed above.